# How to Find & Replace in Jupyter Lab and limit just the selected cell?

Tags: python, plugins, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to know if there is some plugin or configuration to habilited this function.
[Find and replace exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT6nP.png)

Some sugestion how to solve my problem.

Comment: This is built-in in JupyterLab since 3.1 release, just upgrade JupyterLab. See the gif in https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6650#issuecomment-879741501.